# Unable to create AVD with android sdk on Mac OS

Tags: android, macos, android-virtual-device

I have installed Android Studio and JDK1.8 on Mac OS. I followed [the instructions](https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html?pkg=studio) and created a new application with API 15 as minimum sdk.

I tried to create an AVD from AVD manager to test my application by selecting create new virtual device->nexus 6->lollipop 22 armeabi_v7a android 5.1.1 as target. When I click finish, it takes me back to the first AVD manager screen without giving any errors and AVD is not created.

Where could be the problem?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds.html
Here is the link from where you can find how to manage avd

Comment: I tried various combinations like nexus 4/5/6 with lollipop 21/22 etc but none of them is created and no error is shown anywhere. It just takes me back to AVD manager screen showing create a virtual device again.

Comment: Did you download your 1.5 sdks ? Take note, the virtual machine takes very long to boot, if you didn't install the intel x86 emulator accelerator haxm.

Comment: How do i check this?

Comment: I downloaded android-studio-ide-141.1980579-mac.dmg from https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html and jdk-8u51-macosx-x64.dmg from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Comment: http://dab1nmslvvntp.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/figure2.jpg  From the Android Studio Tools menu: Tools > Android > SDK Manager.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/v77kyd5dl/

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/jqwkml1tl/

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/uga9eudmh/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to download the SDKs you are interested in from Android Studio Tools menu -> Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager or [image] from the menu bar.

Don't forget to install the intel x86 emulator accelerator haxm from the SDK Manager - this will speed up significantly your android virtual device.

Then proceed as you mentioned in your question.

You can find more information [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html).

EDIT : From the comments your OS X version is 10.7.5 and Android Studio [runs on 10.8.5](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Requirements) so you either :

1. Update your OS X installation
2. Install [Eclipse](https://eclipse.org/) and use the [ADT plugin](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html) from google on your current configuration.

Comment: I have installed intel x86 emulator…  http://postimg.org/image/uga9eudmh/... along with sdks. I also restarted my system after all installations but unable to create AVD.

Comment: try to delete your already created virtual devices and then recreate one and test, don't forget to set the correct SDK.

Comment: AVD manager is not showing any AVDs to delete. It shows the "create a virtual device screen" whenever i click and comes back to the same screen after creating AVD.

Comment: you could try downloading the latest sdk version then trying to create a new AVD with nexus for instance. this should eliminate the possibility that the device + configuration you want to use are incompatible.

Comment: if this doesn't work, there might be some problems with your installation, and instead of debugging and spending time on this, you should just delete it, and install again, fresh. let me know how this works for you.

Comment: I have uninstalled android studio and installed a fresh copy from http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/sdk/index.html?utm_campaign=android-studio-1-3&utm_source=dac&utm_medium=blog. It is the latest version. I got this error after installing:

Comment: I have uninstalled android studio and downloaded and installed a fresh. It is the latest version. I got this error after installing: Downloading android-sdk_r22.6.2-macosx.zip from https://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r22.6.2-macosx.zip
Unpacking android-sdk_r22.6.2-macosx.zip
….  Done. 10 packages installed.
Android SDK is up to date.
Running Intel® HAXM installer
Silent installation Pass! 
Creating Android virtual device
Unable to create a virtual device: Unable to create Android virtual device

Comment: Now when I create a new project and try to run by creating AVD from manager, it shows this screen http://postimg.org/image/e4kze26lf/ and then this one http://postimg.org/image/703650zc3/. What do I do?

Comment: These are the snapshots of installed tools from sdk manager: http://postimg.org/image/vgrdyixft/ , http://postimg.org/image/banvzn1s9/

Comment: What version of OS X are you using ? There might be some inconsistencies if it's not the latest. Also check your java version.

Comment: Mac OS x 10.7.5, java 1.8.0_51

Comment: Delete all your AVDs if any, open SDK Manager and use the "Tools" in the menu to manually enter the data to create an AVD. Seems like there are problems with the Android Studio, your OS is too old.

Comment: If you can't update your OS, you might consider installing [Eclipse](https://eclipse.org/) and the [plugin from google](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html) to develop Android apps. Let me know if you encounter any problems.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Requirements 

Mac® OS X® 10.8.5 or higher, up to 10.9 (Mavericks), hence you need either to update your Mac OS or to use the previously mentioned method.

Comment: OK… it needs 10.8 or 10.9!

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try to run on a real device instead for emulator and if that too doesn't woek, will try to update my OS X. Have a great weekend!

Comment: Consider selecting this answer to your question, updated the answer above. A great weekend to you too !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31800711/version-or-android-studio-for-mac-osx-10-7-5 … Please answer.