# Version of Android studio for Mac OSX 10.7.5

Tags: android, macos, android-virtual-device

I tried to install the latest version of Android studio on my OS x 10.7.5 but the AVD requires 10.8.5 or higher upto 10.9. It is not possible right now to update OSx, instead we decided to get a working version of android studio.

Which version of Android studio would work on Mac OSX 10.7.5?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31747416/unable-to-create-avd-with-android-sdk-on-mac-os shows the problems i had with incompatible versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three options from what I see here :

1. You install ubuntu (I recommend [Linux Mint 17.2 "Rafaela" - Xfce RC (32-bit)](http://www.linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=193) as it's lighter on your CPU and RAM) and [dual boot](http://www.howtogeek.com/187410/how-to-install-and-dual-boot-linux-on-a-mac/). You don't need to update your Mac OS 10.7.5, it will remain intact, but you will boot on linux to develop Android Apps.
   There you can [install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28314139/how-to-install-android-studio-in-ubuntu) the latest version of [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) with no hassle.
2. Go with the previous Android Development solution : [Eclipse IDE Indigo or higher](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/marsr) + [ADT bundle plugin](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html). Check to see what version of JDK worked on 10.7.5, install it, then install one of the versions of eclipse from Indigo to Mars and then install the above mentioned plugin.
3. You can try to [download](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/beta) and run the first Android Develop Studio Beta that ever appeared on the website (0.8.0), I don't think they ever supported 10.7.5, but you can try.

My suggestion is to try to install linux (point 1) (maybe with the help of a friend), because it's important to have the latest SDK version and the latest updates. 
+ It's easier to work with.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to install linux and let you know!

Comment: With the latest version of Android studio on OS x 10.7.5, I am able to build the project successfully! So If I try to test on a real device instead of emulator, do you think it will work?

Comment: Definitely, if your android device's version is below your max version and above your min version + if you install adb. (not sure if it runs / needs to be installed on 10.7.5 - it's the debug bridge, but surely it works on linux mint :D )

Comment: Btw, they say they still don't support 10.7.5, so you might be having only good luck with this project. I suggest you do the linux install today, because you never know when you need to finish a project and it blows up in your face, and you need to spend time on that when you have none. Spend time, when you have and create a backup system to run and finish your Android projects.

Comment: I agree, Thank you! But I didn't start any real projects. I am just running sample codes and many samples are built successfully on this os. only running them was a problem.

Comment: I have downloaded the linux mint ….iso file. How do I proceed to install with dual boot?

Comment: i mentioned that above "dual boot" follow that guide