# Android SDK on Mac: jspawnhelper quit unexpectedly

Tags: java, android, macos, android-studio

I just installed Android Studio (after wiping everything away from previous installations of either android studio and android SDK), I created a new app (from the templates, didn't edit anything), and I tried to run it in an emulator. I went through the process of creating a AVD (which crashes from Android Studio, but works if I start the tool directly from outside), but no matter what, it fails to run.

I always get a "jspawnhelper quit unexpectedly." error.

My system:

- OSX 10.7.5 (and don't ask me to upgrade, please)
- Java 1.7.0_79 (I also tried with 1.8, it's worse)
- Android Studio 2.1.1
- Android

SDK for API 23 and 22 installed today.

I have no clue what jspawnhelper is, and honestly, I couldn't care less. I just want to install Android Studio and start writing some code.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I found the answer and, as usual, is not the answer I want to hear ... 
Android Studio requires OSX 10.8.5.

[unable to create AVD with android sdk on Mac OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31747416/unable-to-create-avd-with-android-sdk-on-mac-os)

I'm not upgrading this macbook even if somebody points a gun at me ... time to go shopping, or install linux.